# sql opendatasource need to access files on a mapped network drive

Tags: sql, openrowset

I have a number of files in different formats (Excel, Access, and CSV) saved on a network drive and I need to use `opendatasource` and `openrowset` to insert the data into a SQL table.  These queries will only work if the files are saved on the SQL server.  Is there a way to get around this?

I have admin rights on my local machine and on the server with full read/write permissions.  The drives are also mapped on the server.  Here are the queries and the error messages that I am getting:

```
SELECT Seq, Label
FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source = "G:\IMA Utilization Reports\\IMAv2k.mdb"' )...BackupLabels
```

Results in: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "'G:\IMA Utilization Reports\DB\IMAv2k.mdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".

```
SELECT Seq, Label
FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source = "\\172.16.0.32\Finance\IMA Utilization Reports\DB\IMAv2k.mdb"' )...BackupLabels;
```

Results in: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\172.16.0.32\Finance\IMA Utilization Reports\DB\IMAv2k.mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                'excel 12.0;HDR=yes;imex=1;driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; extended properties=excel 12.0 xml; 
                Database=G:\IMA Utilization Reports\Provider ID Numbers.xlsx', 
                'select * from [Employee ID Numbers$]')
```

Results in:  Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

If anyone has an answer or can point me to somewhere that does I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.